# How to Write a Function that Lists Products in a Table Side-by-Side

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a script that allows users on my e-commerce site to select 3 products and it highlights the products as they select.

How can I grab the $pro_image, title, desc, etc. of the 3 products selected and put them into a table for side-by-side view?

I am assuming we will somehow need to check for the $pro_id that is selected to identify each product separately?

```
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <h4>Not sure which product to choose? <br> Select up to 3 and compare side-by-side.</h4>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <button type="compare" class="btn btn-success" name="submit-compare">Compare</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
          <?php getpcatpro();

          $get_products = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,9";
          $run_products = mysqli_query($con,$get_products);

          while($row_products=mysqli_fetch_array($run_products)){

            $pro_id = $row_products['product_id'];
            $pro_title = $row_products['product_title'];
            $pro_img1 = $row_products['product_img1'];
            $pro_link = $row_products['product_link'];

            echo "
            <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6'>
              <div class='product' onclick='highlight(this)'>
                <center>
                  <img class='img-responsive' src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_img1'>
                </center>
                <div class='text'>
                  <center>
                    <a href='$pro_link'> $pro_title </a>
                  </center>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>  ";
          }
          ?>

          <script>
            var selected_items = 0;
            function highlight(target) {
              if(target.style.border == ""){
                if(selected_items < 3){
                  target.style.border = "1px solid red";
                  selected_items += 1;
                }
              } else{
                target.style.border = "";
                selected_items -= 1;
              }
            }
          </script>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there's no button type called 'compare', please stick to standards, you shouldn't put random things into these attributes, you can create your own if need be (which I do not think you need to). See here for the three types you are allowed: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp (you should just use 'button')

Second, do not add styles through JS, you will cause an entire repaint every time you change a pixel. Instead, toggle class names on the class attribute of an element, let CSS do the work of styling, and JS do the work of interaction.

Thirdly, move all 'PHP' to the top of your script (such as defining your SQL statement and fetching the result of it) rather than having these things interspersed within HTML (just use PHP later in the document to build HTML from the PHP variables at the top of the script), such as looping through your result set to build out the HTML, not to perform important tasks such fetching the data itself, this will help you track whats doing what where so you don't tie yourself up in IF statements etc.

OK, Create a function, bound to your compare button, that toggles the state of an element. Instead of 'highlighting' using styles, toggle a class 'compare' on the product parent container:

```
<style>
.product.compare{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
<script>
$('.btn.compare').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.product').toggleClass('compare');
});
</script>
<div class='products'>
  <div class='product' data-id='1'>
    <h2>A Product</h2>
    <button class='btn compare'>compare</button>
  </div>
  <div class='product' data-id='2'>
    <h2>Another Product</h2>
    <button class='btn compare'>compare</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will basically, when the button is clicked, find the parent element with class '.product' then toggle the class '.compare' on it, so you should have `.product.compare`

You'll need to design your table to have fixed rows with class names, like so:

```
<table class='comparison'>
  <thead>
    <tr class='product-title'></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='product-price'></tr>
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

Once you have products with a toggled state (a class has been added which both highlights the row with CSS visibly, but also flags it for comparison to jQuery, create a new button and method for it to call to build the comparison table

`<button class='btn goCompare'>Go Compare</button>`

```
$(function(){

  $(".btn.goCompare").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    buildComparisonTable();
  });

});

function buildComparisonTable(){

    var comparisonTableBody = $('table.comparison tbody');
    var comparisonTableBodyProductTitleCol = $('table.comparison thead tr.product-title');
    var comparisonTableBodyProductPriceCol = $('table.comparison tbody tr.product-price');

    comparisonTableBody.find('.product-col').remove();

    $('.product.compare').each(function(){

      var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); 
        var title = $(this).attr('data-title'); 
        var price = $(this).attr('data-price'); 

        comparisonTableBodyProductTitleCol.append('<th class="product-col">'+title+'</th>'); 
        comparisonTableBodyProductPriceCol.append('<td class="product-col">'+price+'</td>'); 

    });
}
```

The choice is yours, but think about how you can cleverly and correctly mark up your pages to be easily read by your scripts. You can either stuff all of the product data into attributes on a parent element:

```
<div class='product' data-id='1' data-title='A Product' data-price='$10.00' data-primary-category='Homeware'>
  <h2>A Product</h2>
  <button class='btn compare'>compare</button>
</div>
```

Or you can add a class to each element that has the data you intend to gleam:

```
<div class='product' data-id='1'>
    <h2 class='product-title'>A Product</h2>
    <span class='product-price'>$10.00</span>
    <span class='product-category'>Homeware</span>
    <img class='product-img' src='/images/product-1.jpg' />
</div>
```

Now you can target what you want easily and get information from it using proper class names, a considered layout, correct use of technologies and a simple approach. This code-pen illustrates: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/voBKgV

Comment: I am sorry, the code I provided was more for illustrative purposes, I didn't test it and there are a couple of mistakes in there (I have edited the post). I have created this code-pen, it has a working prototype of what you need. Study and extend / modify it for your purposes: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/voBKgV (make sure you include jQuery in your project).

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to help out. One last question, is there any way to get rid of the "compare" buttons under the products and just make it so that the product gets highlighted when the user actually clicks on the product itself?

Comment: I've modified the code-pen, you can change `$('.product.compare').click(...` to `$('.product').click(...` and delete the button HTML and just clicking inside a .product container, so anything in the div including text / images / links (so be careful) will call the click function. For usability though, you'll need to indicate to users that they can click on the product to add it to a comparison table, so having a button or icon or checkbox or something isn't the worst idea in the world, you want your UI to be intuitive to use as well as elegant.

Comment: Thanks! I plan on having some text to inform the user that they can click on products. Btw everything works besides the red border being added? Is there a possibility that I'm including JQuery wrong? I have the class set up in my CSS file but still nothing.

Comment: If a class is being toggled and the comparison table is populating, the jQuery would be working fine. If you can see the 'compare' class appearing on the 'product' element upon 'inspection' (if you are not aware, you can use Chrome / FireFox to inspect the DOM, just right-click), I suspect you have a CSS issue. Make sure your stylesheet is included and you've correctly defined the class names, there's probably something small and silly and obvious hiding in plain sight. Don't be tempted to do it in JS, it's bad practice, you'll find the answer.

Comment: Hey, is there any way to add a column all the way to the left with titles for each row? These would be static values not dynamic.

Comment: You can add the 'title' cells in your initial table markup (and remove the thead) like so:
```<tbody>
    <tr class='product-title'>
      <th>Product</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class='product-price'>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>```
and modify 2 lines in your JS like so:
`var comparisonTableBodyProductTitleCol = $('table.comparison tbody tr.product-title')` (uses tbody instead of thead)
and
`comparisonTableBodyProductTitleCol.append('<td class="product-col">'+title+'</td>');` (writes td instead of th).
Then it's good to go.

Comment: I believe this would always leave the two static values showing, even when the table is hidden. https://codepen.io/stojanovr/pen/MWgLeOq

Comment: It wouldn't be a terrible idea to always show a comparison table waiting for selections, but if you want to make the whole thing invisible you already have the tools. The code I have provided already offers you a mechanism for hiding and showing things according to a click event. Modify / extend what is already there to render the table invisible (default state in CSS) and upon your 'compare' click toggle a class on the table / its container to reveal it `table.show{display: block;}`